# null pointer exception on initialized array

Tags: arrays, nullpointerexception

When I try to run my program, I get a null pointer exception in line 8, (basePoints[i].x3D = (int) (R*Math.cos(i*T));). This happens immediately as i = 0 at run time. I do not understand what I have done wrong I have initialized basePoints with, (Point3D[] basePoints = new Point3D[50];)

Can someone please help me with this?

```
    Cone newCone = new Cone();
    final int H = newCone.HEIGHT;
    final int R = newCone.RADIUS;
    Point3D[] basePoints = new Point3D[50];         //50 points around the base of the cone
    final double T = 2*Math.PI/basePoints.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < basePoints.length; i++) {
        basePoints[i].x3D = (int) (R*Math.cos(i*T));
        basePoints[i].y3D = (int) (R*Math.sin(i*T));    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the first line in your loop should be `basePoints[i] = new Point3D();` so the loop is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < basePoints.length; i++) {
    basePoints[i] = new Point3D();
    basePoints[i].x3D = (int) (R*Math.cos(i*T));
    basePoints[i].y3D = (int) (R*Math.sin(i*T));    
}
```

The line `Point3D[] basePoints = new Point3D[50];` reserve the space in memory for 50 Point3D instances, but it does not initialize them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new `Point3D` object and put it into the array position before assigning values to it:

```
...

for (int i = 0; i < basePoints.length; i++) {
    basePoints[i] = new Point3D();
    basePoints[i].x3D = (int) (R*Math.cos(i*T));
    basePoints[i].y3D = (int) (R*Math.sin(i*T));    
}

...
```

Comment: Oh, OK, thank you. I thought that all of the basePoints would initialize in my first declaration of the array. I didn't know that I had to initialize each basePoints[i];

Comment: @Raisintoe Good. If one of the answers here worked out for you, please accept it and perhaps upvote it.